# Программа с eval вылетает даже без исключений

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

Есть огромное арифметическое выражение (Почти мегабайт текста). Я его пытаюсь запихнуть в eval.

Программа вылетает и даже не даёт никаких исключений.

Лимит рекурсии увеличил до `30000`, но это не помогло.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что вылетает? Может, оно успешно выполняется и завершается, ничего не выводя? Приведите хотя бы примерный ваш код что ли

Comment: @andreymal Логично, что программа вылетает, потому что код после eval не выполняется. Привожу код и входной файл соответственно: https://pastebin.com/bEkrmCYF https://anonfile.com/c0I8bce1bf/oddoreven.in

Comment: Вылетает не без исключений, а с ошибкой сегментирования `segfault at 7ffe49398ff8 ip 000000000056d034 sp 00007ffe49399000 error 6 in python3.5[400000+3a9000]`

Comment: И вылетает потому, что переполняется системный стек. Если убрать ограничение у него (`ulimit -s unlimited`), то код успешно выполняется и печатает `evaled 50`

Comment: Не надо вычислять "огромные арифметические выражения" с помощью `eval`. Посмотрите например [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Comment: @Scrabyte Понимаю и знаю все минусы eval, но то была олимпиадная задача, там красивый ввод гарантирован.